# VB6 IDE can change the case of builti-in functions, objects, etc

Tags: vb6

I've seen other similar posts but didn't find one that would explain why it would change the case of built-in functions and objects

For example, in my VB6 project if I enter a line of code as:

```
err.Raise 513
```

after I hit return, the IDE automatically changes the "err" to "Err".
But in another project, it does just the opposite! I enter:

```
Err.Raise 513
```

and after hitting return it changes the "Err" to "err".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA object properties appear in lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640121/vba-object-properties-appear-in-lower-case)

Comment: What evidence do you have that this works differently for built-ins vs anything else?

Comment: @StayOnTarget, by 'built-in' I meant anything that isn't user-defined. If it's user-defined then the user has declared its name and VB6 will change all occurrences of references to it to match whatever changes the user makes to the case of any letters in the name. The point I was trying to make is that if you introduce a user-defined name that doesn't conflict with a built-in name (i.e. doesn't give you a compile error, for example, a go-to label), then you might be left wondering why the case of a built-in name has changed.

Comment: I agree that the IDE's behavior here is unexpected to say the least.

Comment: Yes.  VB6 is in essence a case-insensitive language, and tries to enforce the same casing across all objects in all files (as you open/edit/save them).  It's something you just get used to... Or build a separate text file containing a bunch of well-known var names with intended casing, of the form `Dim myVar` for each one, and then paste and delete it.  VB6 isn't the best at things, and uses the most recently defined version.  This, this resets it for well-known names, at least until you define one the other way.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a goto label anywhere in your project, and that goto label is the name of a built-in function or object, then all occurrences of that built-in function or object will have their case changed to match the case of your label!

So, don't use built-in names for goto labels!